# How to clear HTML input tag after alert is generated

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the function below to generate an alert when the entered number is not an integer. But I also need to clear the HTML form. I used `id.value= "";` but that didn't work. Any suggestions are welcome:

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
  if (!(x === parseInt(x, 10))) {
    alert("Empployee ID can be integer numbers only.");
    id.value = "";
  } else {

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header1">
  <input type="text" id="ename" onblur="myFunction('ename')" name="name" placeholder="Enter Employee ID" required="" />
</div>
```

Comment: -1 I would suggest you to make some debug of the code: a vulgar console.log(), or using a javascript debugger (included in every major browser) would expose you the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your `id.value` is not a HTML element. You are trying to get an access to `value` property of id variable... Something like this `"ename".value`

Try this:

```
document.getElementById(id).value = 'VALUE';
```

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
  
  if (!(x === parseInt(x, 10))) {
  
    alert("Empployee ID can be integer numbers only.");
    document.getElementById(id).value = "";
  } 
  else {

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header1">
  <input type="text" id="ename" onblur="myFunction('ename')" name="name"  placeholder="Enter Employee ID" required="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting empty string in the value property of `id`. `id` is a `string`. Hence, it won't work you need to put an empty string somewhere in the document where the id attribute is equal to the function argument.

you need to use :

```
document.getElementById(id).value = "";
```

Comment: @user3250190 I hope you know why it wasn't working. Please accept my answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `id.value`
because the `id` passed in you function was a string.
Since you already passed the `id` then maybe you can use:

`document.getElementById(id).value = "";`

**Answer Explained**

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. While this may answer the question, it would help the OP to understand if you could explain why the OP's code didn't work and how your code fixes it.